# MapView doesn't work correctly in Recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-mapview

can someone please give me some advice how I can get a Recyclerview working with a Google Mapview in Lite Mode? I have set up a Recyclerview where i want to show multiple Mapviews. When I open the fragment with the recyclerview the mapviews that are out of the visible area in the recyclerview dont update their cameraMovement. After opening the fragment again, everything is fine and all Mapviews get updated. If i close the app then and start it again, the mapviews that are out of the visible area dont get updated again...

As you can see below in the AdapterCode i have set a Log output in the moveMap() method that gets called by the onMapReadyCallback(). If i scroll through the recyclerview i can see that this method gets called properly, but strangely the maps outside the initially visible area of the recyclerview dont get their camera Update. Can somebody please tell me what I am doing wrong?

This is how i setup the recyclerview in the fragment:

```
mAdapter = new FragmentGPSRoutesAdapter(getContext(), routeList, waypointList);
RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
```

Below you can see the actual recyclerview Adapter:

```
public class FragmentGPSRoutesAdapter extends
    RecyclerView.Adapter<FragmentGPSRoutesAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private List<Route> routeList;
    private List<Waypoint> waypointList;
    private Map<Long, ArrayList<Waypoint>> maps;
    private Context mContext;

    private static final int VIEW_TYPE_ROUTE = 1;
    private static final int VIEW_TYPE_EMPTY = 2;

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements OnMapReadyCallback{
        public TextView tvRouteName, tvFrom, tvTo;

        public GoogleMap gMap;
        public MapView map;

        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);

            map = (MapView) view.findViewById(R.id.ivMap);
            if (map != null)
            {
                map.onCreate(null);
                map.getMapAsync(this);
            }

            tvRouteName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvRouteName);
            tvFrom = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvFrom);
            tvTo = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvTo);
        }

        @Override
        public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
            MapsInitializer.initialize(mContext);
            gMap = googleMap;
            gMap.getUiSettings().setMapToolbarEnabled(false);

            moveMap(gMap);
        }
    }

    public void moveMap(GoogleMap gMap) {
        Log.v("LOG", "mapMoved: " + gMap);
        LatLng latlng = new LatLng(52.3905217, 9.6996769);
        CameraUpdate cu = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latlng, 14);
        gMap.moveCamera(cu);
    }

    public FragmentGPSRoutesAdapter(Context mContext, List<Route> routeList, List<Waypoint> waypointList) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.routeList = routeList;
        this.waypointList = waypointList;

        createWaypointHashmap();
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView;
        if (viewType == VIEW_TYPE_ROUTE) {
            itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.fragment_gps_route_list_row, parent, false);
        } else {
            itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.fragment_gps_empty, parent, false);
        }

        return new ViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        int viewType = getItemViewType(position);
        if (viewType == VIEW_TYPE_ROUTE) {
            final Route route = routeList.get(position);

            // Show Routename with date
            holder.tvRouteName.setText(route.getName() + " - " + FormatTimestamp.showDate(mContext, route.getStartTime()));

            // Show Route Start/Destination Address
            holder.tvFrom.setText(route.getStartAddress());
            holder.tvTo.setText(route.getDestinationAddress());

        } else if (viewType == VIEW_TYPE_EMPTY) {
            // Do nothing here...
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        if (routeList.size() == 0) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return routeList.size();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if (routeList.size() == 0)
            return VIEW_TYPE_EMPTY;
        else
            return VIEW_TYPE_ROUTE;
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call:

```
map.onResume();
```

After your:

```
map.onCreate(null);
```

For your view to update correctly